# How to get min value in elasticsearch curl command

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, logstash

I am newbie to elasticsearch. I want to get min value from particular day of my log line's field. My Kibana shows indexed data as follows:

```
@timestamp      2015-07-30T22:22:07.071-07:00

@version        1

type        mtaLogs

Integerdata     052256894-0400

msgType     received from internet

msgid       qamail-4.02.0220150730080248.IJRUJ.email-qa-sun26@172.20.1.10

msgsize     5635

path        /opt/user1/log/mta.log

processID       23441

protocol        SMTP

rcpts       pd10@myoxdomain.com

sender      pd9@myoxdomain.com

servername      mta

sid     4F9F325E-8DECDB12-00003556.1

time        0

traceName       MsgTrace
```

I want the min value of `msgsize` from curl coomand.

My curl command is as follows:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                        {
                        "match" : {
                                "type" : "mtaLogs"
                        }},
                        {
                        "match" : {
                                "msgType" : "received from internet"
                        }}  ,
                        {
                        "filtered" : {
                        "filter" : {
                                "range" : {
                                        "@timestamp" : {
                                                "from" : "2015-07-30T00:00:00",
                                                "to" : "2015-07-30T23:59:59"
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        }
                        }
                ]
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
          "min_size" : {
                   "min" : {
                          "field" : "msgsize"
                    }
           }
     }
}'
```

But I am getting exception as follows:

```
 "index" : "logstash-2015.07.30",
      "shard" : 4,
      "status" : 500,
      "reason" : "ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]"
    } ]
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "min_size" : {
      "value" : null
    }
  }
}
```

though I am parsing those fields correctly as:

```
msgsize=%{INT:msgsize:int}
```

Can anyone help me here, as what went wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that some of your documents have a `msgsize` field with a string value instead? Maybe a document created with a previous logstash configuration where `msgsize` was not an `INT`?

Comment: Yes. When I got this exception and searched then from one of the post I realized that I need to parse data in logstash as `msgsize=%{INT:msgsize:int}` instead of `msgsize=%{INT:msgsize}`. So is this the reason?

Comment: Yes, most probably, because some documents have `msgsize` as string and some others have `msgsize` as int. The exception you get is typical of such a situation. You best bet is to wipe and reindex your logs with your latest config.

Comment: Yes...that was the issue.. I wiped out all data and indexed again with new grok.... and now it worked..
Thanks Val...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you get is typical of a situation where documents have been indexed with logstash with a previous configuration where the `msgsize` field wasn't properly mapped to an INT and then the configuration was changed. So you end up with some documents having `msgsize` as a string and others with `msgsize` as an int, hence the exception.

The only solution I see here, is wiping your indexes and re-indexing your logs with your latest configuration.